# Listar los elementos de una matriz en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo el siguente array:

```
array = [['director@contraportada.net'], ['arturo@casi.es', 'protecciondatos@casi.es', 'jafunes@casi.es', 'vkinh@casi.es', 'avalverde@casi.es']]
```

como puedo hacer para que me saque el resultado ha esto:

```
'director@contraportada.net'
'arturo@casi.es'
'protecciondatos@casi.es'
'jafunes@casi.es'
'vkinh@casi.es'
'avalverde@casi.es'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes exactamente una matriz, más bien una lista de listas. La forma iterativa más clásica sería hacer algo así:

```
for lista in array:
  for elemento in lista:
    print(elemento)
```

Recorremos cada lista dentro de `array` y luego cada elemento de estas listas.

Otra forma bien compacta, que básicamente es similar a la anterior, es usar "comprensión de listas"

```
print("\n".join([elemento for lista in array for elemento in lista]))
```

En este caso, lo que logramos es una lista "plana" con todos los elementos, y luego concatenamos todos estos en una cadena separada por salto de linea.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer por ejemplo:

```
for element in array:
    for subElement in element:
        print(subElement)
```

o lo que sería lo mismo:

```
[print(subElement) for element in array for subElement in element]
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
from functools import reduce
array = [['director@contraportada.net'], ['arturo@casi.es', 'protecciondatos@casi.es', 'jafunes@casi.es', 'vkinh@casi.es', 'avalverde@casi.es']]

for x in reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,array):
    print(x)
```